# Rule clarification for Enlightened badge

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

Can anyone tell me what the rules are for an Enlightened Badge?

Although I have an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615334/a-tool-like-resharper-but-for-java/615352#615352) with 11 up votes I still haven't received this badge.

Comment: Damn that Jon Skeet! He foiled our plots again!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615334/a-tool-like-resharper-but-for-java/615346#615346) with the same timestamp as yours.

Looking at the answer id numbers, yours is 615352 the other one is 615346, so it looks like the other answer was first by a few seconds.

You only get the <kbd>Enlightened</kbd> badge if yours is the first undeleted answer.

Comment: It wouldn't even need to be a few seconds, a few milliseconds would be enough.

Comment: Good point there Brad!

Comment: Small addendum: if the earlier answers are deleted, you also receive the badge :)

Comment: I've an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822372/how-to-use-values-in-textbox-of-a-form-in-another-form/18822420#18822420) which is the 1st answer and with a score of 10, but have not received any Enlightened badge :(

Comment: @Nadeem_MK - the post only has **one** vote which gives you 10 reputation. The **score** is the total of `upvotes - downvotes`. It also needs to be the **accepted** answer - which again, your's isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was not the first to the question. It needs to be for "enlightened".