# Suggested minor modification to the Electorate Badge description

Tags: feature-request, badges, electorate-badge

I admit that I was one of the bunch that didn't understand the infamous [Electorate Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate) at first; at some point I did some research on Meta, and found its meaning.

I've been thinking about it for a while, and I finally dared step into the Electorate Badge's *No Man's Land!* I am here proposing a very minor modification from:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

To

1. > Voted on **at least** 600 questions and 25% or more of **your** total votes are on questions.
2. > Voted on **at least** 600 questions, and **where** 25% or more of **your** total votes **were** on questions.
3. > Voted on **a minimum of** 600 questions, **where at least** 25% of **your** total votes **were** on questions.

The fact that the word *questions* is repeated twice causes confusion, because when reading the description (even after the umpteenth time), it is *still* confusing. <del>one tends to associate both instances of the word *questions* to **literally** represent questions.</del>

---

Even though there is a very extensive and helpful Community Wiki on Meta, [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399); it isn't readily available from the Badges page - maybe it can be added?

Those who frequent Meta, already know how many questions pop up related to the Electorate Badge...for those who don't, here's a *short* list:

- [Clarify Electorate badge wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording)
- [The Electorate badge's description is unclear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131977/the-electorate-badges-description-is-unclear)
- [How can we reword the description for the Electorate badge so that it is less confusing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102868/how-can-we-reword-the-description-for-the-electorate-badge-so-that-it-is-less-co)
- [Electorate badge question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78511/electorate-badge-question)
- [Electorate badge rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules)
- [On exactly what criteria is the Electorate badge awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71693/on-exactly-what-criteria-is-the-electorate-badge-awarded)
- [Rule clarification for Enlightened badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/rule-clarification-for-enlightened-badge)

---

## **Update**

I've made a mistake on my initial suggestion; I've updated it since.

---

**Your thoughts?**

Comment: But that's incorrect... you do need to **vote on at least 600 *questions***, not posts.

Comment: @animuson Thanks - I just caught on to that from your comment. I've updated my question with better suggestions.

Comment: I don't see how those words you're adding in make the text any more clear. They're just extra words taking up space...

Comment: The extra words are improving the sentences' grammar and meaning, and therefore making them easier to understand. Typically developers try to *shorten* descriptions because **we** understand what they mean; but that's not always the case for the end-user (especially when stepping into relatively unfamiliar areas).

Comment: I don't see how adding "where" improves the grammar. It actually makes the sentence not make sense. Adding in "your" is useless. Whose votes would you expect them to be? And I really don't see how adding "at least" or "a minimum of" makes it any more clear.

Comment: @animuson You obviously don't agree with my suggestions. Please downvote the post, or suggest your better alternative.

Comment: I like number 3, but I'm verbose. It would probably be too long, causing the description to wrap, and the page layout to break, and the Meta tubes to overflow with bug reports...

Answer (score 7):

I've always thought that was the most confusing badge description. Why not:

> 25% of your total votes are on questions (minimum 600 questions).

That puts the *real* intent of the badge up front and the sub-requirement last.